# Button Click and change int value?

Tags: android, button, click

I make a database app. I have one button and one int value; I need to change int value.

Example = sayi = 1

button 1st. click = sayi = 2
button 2nd. click = sayi = 3

P.s = Sorry, I don't know english very well.

```
int sayi = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);
    final TextView oku = (TextView)findViewById(id.oku);
    final Button diger = (Button)findViewById(id.diger);
    diger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int sayi = 2;
        }
    });


    Veritabani veritabanim;
    veritabanim = new Veritabani(this);
    try {

        veritabanim.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    SQLiteDatabase dbm = veritabanim.getReadableDatabase();



    Cursor c = dbm.rawQuery("SELECT _id,soyleyen,soz FROM sozler WHERE _id = "+sayi+" ", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{

            //assing values
            String column1 = c.getString(0);
            String column2 = c.getString(1);
            String column3 = c.getString(2);
            //Do something Here with values
            oku.setText(column3);

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    dbm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve?

Comment: Replace `int sayi = 2;` with `int sayi += 1;` in the Button's `OnClick()`... But then you should **use it** in some way - this is up to you, to decide what to do with that incremented variable.

Comment: Well, I do quote app. For example i have 1000 quote and if I click button than _id value is change and the quote is change.

Comment: Actually this won't work because he is creating new int in the listner scope. He should use `sayi` variable that is already declared.

Comment: Pfff! Didn't work,  I'm trying 2 hours I'll be crazy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this...

```
int sayi = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(layout.activity_main);
Button diger = (Button)findViewById(id.diger);
diger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sayi++;
        getDBOperation();
    }
});
}

private void getDBOperation()
{
    TextView oku = (TextView)findViewById(id.oku);

    Veritabani veritabanim;
    veritabanim = new Veritabani(this);
    try {
        veritabanim.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    SQLiteDatabase dbm = veritabanim.getReadableDatabase();

   Cursor c = dbm.rawQuery("SELECT _id,soyleyen,soz FROM sozler WHERE _id = "+sayi+" ", null);
   if(c.moveToFirst()){
       do{
          //assing values
         String column1 = c.getString(0);
         String column2 = c.getString(1);
         String column3 = c.getString(2);
         //Do something Here with values
         oku.setText(column3);
       }while(c.moveToNext());
  }
  c.close();
  dbm.close();
  }
```